# How can I test a function that uses complex objects from an external API?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function:

```
// helper.js
export const someFunction = (complexObj1, complexObj2) => {
  const someObj = complexObj1.generateAnObject();
  const objList = someObj.generateListOfObjects();

  for (const obj of objList) {
    obj.performAction();
  }
};
```

As you can see, it's a pretty much a void function that performs a bunch of tasks.  The "complexObj1" and "complexObj2" objects and the functions it has attached to them are all generated from an API I am using.

Things I would like to test:

- parameters complexObj1 and complexObj2 are valid objects
- someObj within fucntion is a valid object with maybe checking a certain property exists
- objList returns a valid list
- each obj in the loop is a valid object

What is the right way to test a function like this?  I've looked into Jest mocking but I'm not sure if this fits my scenario.

```
  test("Test someFunction", () => {
    // not sure what to do here or what to mock etc
  });
```

Can I not test functions like this?

If anyone can give me an example of how to test this or even just point me in the right direction I would be thankful.  I really want to learn how to do this.

Comment: None of the things you say you want to test are the responsibility of the function you've shown. What's the *behaviour* of that function? An empty test function isn't a legitimate attempt.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hey thanks for responding.  I guess i'm just trying to make sure everything is running correctly as this will be a product used by quite a few users.  if this function were to actually return an object, would the only scenario for me to test is just to make sure the object returned is valid?  otherwise if the function doesn't return anything, there's nothing to test?  Is that correct?

Comment: *"if the function doesn't return anything, there's nothing to test?"* - what about its side effects? If it doesn't return anything *or otherwise do anything* there's nothing to test, but then what's the point in it existing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the point of this function in particular is to perform some necessary actions and for organization really.  but hm i guess i can test the side effects like you mentioned outside of this function.. okay at least you're steering me in the direction i'm looking for so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the function accepts an object, calls a function on that object to generate a different object, calls a function on that object to generate an array, then calls a function on each object in the array.

Since it only knows about what is passed to it, you can pass appropriate mock data and use [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) to confirm that it is working properly:

```
const someFunction = (complexObj1) => {
  const someObj = complexObj1.generateAnObject();
  const objList = someObj.generateListOfObjects();

  for (const obj of objList) {
    obj.performAction();
  }
};

test('someFunction', () => {
  const objList = [
    { performAction: jest.fn() },
    { performAction: jest.fn() }
  ];
  const obj = {
    generateAnObject: () => ({
      generateListOfObjects: () => objList
    })
  };
  someFunction(obj);
  expect(objList[0].performAction).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  expect(objList[1].performAction).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

Comment: thank you for actually finding time to answer instead of downvoting.  this is perfect and leads me into the direction i'm looking for.  thank you so much